# Off heap not working when query parallelism is set

Tags: ignite

We are trying 1.9 query parallelism in the cache config but It doesn't  work with off heap.If we comment out parallelism everything works fine.  Paralellism works fine with on heap .

Are we missing anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known bug [1] that already fixed and merged to master branch. You can apply it to 1.9 and build ignite from sources.

[1] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-4826

Comment: How can we get the latest stable snapshot build from this master branch ?

Comment: Thanks. i was able to download 2.0.0 snapshot which seems to be working